# ERROR 3 (HY000): Error writing file './binlog.index_crash_safe' (OS errno 28 - No space left on device)

Tags: mysql, docker

I use `mysql` in `docker` and my server's space is 100% full.

Half of space is occupied by `/var/lib/mysql/binlog.*` files and I want to remove them with the following command:

```
purge binary logs to 'binlog.000142';
```

Error is:

```
ERROR 3 (HY000): Error writing file './binlog.index_crash_safe' (OS errno 28 - No space left on device)
```

As recommended in StackOverFlow by community in other questions, it's not recommended to remove `rm binlog` via the OS and it's better to remove by mysql query.

What should I do in this case? Should I add hard disk to my server? Or there's a way to remove that?

Answer (score 0):

As I had no other choices, I removed some other files in the server (not related to mysql), so I freed about 4GB, then ran this query in mysql:

```
purge binary logs to 'binlog.000142';
```

It is safe to run this query and you can run with no fear.

Just note that running this query removes files older than `binlog.000142' (not this file itself):

```
binlog.000141
binlog.000140
.
.
.
```

It keeps `binlog.000142`, `binlog.000143` and newer files.